Safari keeps logging me out every time when using 'Show features for web developers'
This question has been asked and sometimes answered already. What's different is that I want to keep 'Show features for web developers' enabled.
System
macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
Safari Version 17.4.1 (19618.1.15.11.14)
The issue
Safari constantly logs me out of all web apps which is very annoying: GMail, SO, OpenAI, etc.
I want to use developer features, primarily because of being able to use 'Inspect element' when building web apps.
The solution
If I disable 'Show features for web developers' the issue goes away, but as indicated I want to keep using this feature without Safari logging me out everywhere.
What I have tried / the settings

In Settings -> Privacy:

'Prevent cross site tracking' is OFF
'Hide IP address from trackers' is OFF


In Settings -> Developers: everything is unchecked
In Settings -> Feature Flags: everything is set to default


Are you talking about the "Develop" menu bar item?

The 'Develop' menu bar item shows up when you enable Settings -> Advanced -> Show features for web developers. So it's a result of the setting that I have enabled and that I want to have enabled.

Can you post the content of the safari container's preferences plist file? (defaults read com.apple.safari) you may have touched something in "Develop" menubar menu.

I get Domain /Users/username/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari does not exist and tried finding the file in a few different locations but I can not seem to locate it.

I don't know how that could happen... And I don't have a mac with me now. But maybe you should investigate that before proceeding.

It is possible that that toggle also enables many other debug preferences to be recognized.

Yes, it probably does. The question is: which one(s) cause the logouts?
